# What does "get in" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am unable to understand what does the following sentence mean:

> I will do something when I get in.

Comment: I'm not sure of your context, but when I hear someone say that, it usually means *when I get in to the office.* It is just shortened.

Comment: What do you don't understand about the sentence?

Comment: [Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get+in#get__106) -- in addition to *arrive at a destination* it can mean *arrive (at home) (at the office)*

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Or may be he is just waiting outside the gates for the doorman to let him in, and then he will do "something"!

Comment: @Warlock, please consider visiting the new [English Language Learner's site](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It's just gone into beta and a question like this would be a good fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To Arrive**

For example,

"I will run the tests when I get in" -> "I will run the tests when I arrive at the office".